# Django - Default value for the ForeignKey not working. Or is it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So this is my model.py:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="Default Album")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Photo(Image):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

When I try to upload a photo in the admin, there is a drop down list for `Album` field. But there's nothing in it, its blank. I thought it will create a new album with the name 'Default Album', but it just gives me an error. How do I specify the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you are creating a Photo, it's trying to assign the ForeignKey.  If it's blank, there aren't any entries in your Album model.  `default` refers to having the default value on the creation of a new Album instance, such as

```
new_album = Album()
new_album.save() # new_album.name == "Default Album"
```

What you need to do is to create an Album first so the dropdown is populated with at least 1 `Album`.  Then you can create a photo and associate it with the appropriate `Album`.

Additionally, what it sounds like is you want a default `ForeignKey` reference, which you can specific the id to the default instance like `ForeignKey(Album, default=1)` or `default=some_fn`, where `some_fn` looks up the appropriate Album instance.

Comment: Yes! You got me right. What I want is to reference it to the default album, where the Users can save whenever there's no album name given. How do I do that?

Comment: Just define a default to the ForeignKey as I outlined in the last paragraph of the answer.  In some_fn you can do something like `Album.objects.get_or_create(name="Default Album")` to get the default Album as you want.